How can i fix FF console error in VS Code?
    int b = 1, i = 0;
    char str[255];

    printf("Name the students you want to search for: ");
    fflush(stdin); //while ((getchar()) != '\n'); // clear buffer
    gets(str);

    while(i != n && b != 0){
        if(strcmp(str,students[i].name) == 0){
            b = 0;
            printf("| Nr. | \tName |  \tFirst name | Average Mark |\n");
            printf("|%4d |%13s |%15s |%12.2f |\n", i + 1, students[i].name, students[i].first_name, students[i].average_mark);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(b == 1)
        printf("\nNo student with this name was found!");

    printf("\n");
}
void sort(){
    int sorted;
    do{
        sorted = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
            if(students[i].average_mark > students[i+1].average_mark){
                sorted = 0;
                student temp = students[i];
                students[i] = students[i+1];
                students[i+1] = temp;
            }
    }while(sorted == 0);
}

enter image description here
I tried to make a simple program but something goes wrong...can somebody explain me why? i'll be extremely grateful!

Welcome to SO. You have cut your program in half. We cannot compile. Please edit your question to provide a MCVE

What are you using as learning resource? Flushing stdin invokes undefined behaviour. You cannot flush input streams. You also should never use gets. It is considered dangerous and was removed from the standard decades ago.

Generally, you should also increase diagnostics level (-Wall -Wextra -pedantic)

Please revise question and tell us what the problem is.  It's important skill to cultivate.  "something goes wrong" carries no information.
